# Generate Array of Workdays with working hours for each day

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I am trying to generate array which calculates all days of each month and then subtract the weekends, and after that I would like to add 8 hours for each day, so 1 = 8 , 2 = 16 etc. So far I have been able to generate the array with all days of specific month. Trying to subtract the weekends and add 8 hours for each day but no luck so far.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
                        $list=array();
                        $month = 1;
                        $year = 2017;

                        for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
                        {
                            $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);          
                            if (date('m', $time)==$month  && ((date('D', $time) != 'Sat' || (date('D', $time) != 'Sun'))))    

                                $list[]=date('d', $time);
                        }

                        echo "<pre>";
                        print_r($list);
                        echo "</pre>";
                   ?>
```

So the final result should be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0][0] => 01
    [0][1] => 8

    [1][0] => 02
    [1][1] => 16  
    ...

)
```

Basically the goal is to calculate each workday how many hours should contains for a month. After having this information will be able to compare it with today date and see if working hours are completed for this month or not.

Any help is very welcome.

Comment: I'm sure it's just a typo but your if statement should throw an error.

Comment: yes it throw error on the line of  && ((date('d') != 'Sat' || (date('d') != 'Sun')

Comment: I was actually going for the fact that it looks like your missing `))` from the end of it.

Comment: I have edited it but it is not working.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that it was going to solve your issue, I was just pointing out that it was going to throw an error :) Are you ultimately just wanting to know how many weekday working hours (8 per weekday) are in a month or do you need to have it as an array? If you need it as an array could you give a little but more information about how it's meant to be built/formatted as I don't quite understand it from your example.

Comment: I need to generate the exampled array bellow, the current state works only if compassion is == displays only weekends but with != displays everything. and the other thing which is issue how to place 8 and increment it for each day in the multidimensional array at second position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132134/discussion-between-ross-wilson-and-john-siniger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could achieve what your after is to use `DateTime` to keep track of the date:

```
$year = 2017;
$month = 1;

$date = (new Datetime())->setDate($year, $month, 1);

$days = [];
$hours = 0;

foreach (range(1, $date->format('t')) as $i) {

    $hours += $date->format('N') < 6 ? 8 : 0;

    $days[] = [
        'date'  => $date->format('d'),
        'hours' => $hours,
    ];

    $date->modify('+1 day');
}
```

This is what is going on:

1. Set the `DateTime` to be the beginning of the month.
2. foreach(range(...)) s just another way to write `for($i=1;$i<=$date->format('t');$i++)`. `t` will just give you the days in the month.
3. `$date->format('N') < 6` is check if the day of the week is before Saturday. If so increment the `$hours` count by 8.
4. I think the rest is fairly straightforward.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @JohnSiniger Glad I could help!